# Use private GitLab repository with Composer

Tags: composer-php, gitlab

My company has a private GitLab server where I have my projects. Especially, this projet (let's call it "project B"): https://git.my-company-name.com/my-username/my-repo.git. Btw, the command "git clone https://git.my-company-name.com/my-username/my-repo.git" works perfectly, of course.

The content of project A is just a single file (a "test.txt" file) and contains a branch "master" only. Nothing special from now, I'll do something more spectif later, now I just wanna test to ad my project into another one.

Anyway. What I want to do is just add "project B" into the vendor of my main project (let's call it "project A").

So, "in project A, "I added these lines into my composer.json

> 

```
"repositories": [  
>        {  
>            "type": "package",  
>            "package": {  
>                "name": "my-username/my-repo.git",  
>                "version": "0.1.0",  
>                "type": "package",  
>                "source": {  
>                    "url": "git@git.my-company-name.com:my-username/my-pr-repo.git",  
>                    "type": "git",  
>                    "reference": "master"  
>                }  
>            }  
>        }  
>    ]
```

and of course in the same file

```
> "require": {  
>        "my-username/my-repo": "*"  
>    },
```

But I got this error, when I try a simple "composer update" :

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>      - The requested package my-username/my-repo could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>     see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
>   - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems

===>
And I don't know why.

Do you have any suggestion please ?

Comment: You should remove `.git` suffix from package name.

Comment: I did. Thanks. Now it seems to work, even if I have another error message. I'll check it and try to figure out before asking any further help. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Alright. I agree : it works perfectly. Thanks a lot dude, it's awesome ! :)